# JavaScript передать значение из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, как передать значения переменной `s` в другую функцию?

```
function getId() {
    const instance = axios.create({

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    });
    instance.get(proxyurl + url)
        .then(response => {

            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                let s = response.data[i].id
                console.log(response.data[i].id)


            }

        })
}

function sum() {
    const ins = axios.create({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    })
    let urlIssue = 'https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/' + s + '?fields=summary,description';
    ins.get(proxyurl + urlIssue)
        .then(response => {
            let a = response.data[i].summary
            console.log(a)
        })
}
```

Comment: вызвать эту функцию в цикле с параметром `s`?

Comment: getId(s);
Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чем вам

```
let s = response.data[i].id
console.log(s)
```

не вызов?

добавьте параметр

```
function sum(s) {
```

и вызывайте

```
 let s = response.data[i].id
 sum(s)
```

Comment: В пределах этой функции - да, но мне нужно использовать значение этой переменной в другой функции

Comment: Вызовите другую функцию и передайте параметер

Comment: добавьте другую функцию в вопрос и укажите как вам надо использовать s

Comment: Добавил, вот здесь нужно let urlIssue

Comment: @Serjik85 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но при таком способе она стает undefined

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112813/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-serjik85).

Answer (score 0):

При объявлении функции, укажите, что она принимает параметр `function sum(s) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Создай генератор, например, в котором вызывай поочередно функции запросы, логика должна быть следующая +-:

```
function request_1(){
...
return value;
}

function request_2(passValue){
...
return anotherValue;
}

function* stages() {
let tmpValue = yield request_1();
let anotherTmpValue = yield request_1(tmpValue);
}
```

И последнюю функцию необходимо вызвать. Собсно генератор будет ждать окончания запросов, а так же перенесет данные из одной функции в другую. Передать можно, как все данные, полученные в первом запросе, так и переработать логику под запуск илдами в цикле. ИМХО, разумнее будет не дергать каждый раз в цикле в запросы, а постараться данные для суммы занести в один запрос.